# Selenium Phantomjs driver - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I tired to implement Phantomjs driver to Selenium tests but it throws me this error. **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;** 
The Phantom library is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.arquillian.extension/arquillian-phantom-driver version 1.2.1.1 and Java version is 1.8 
Implementation looks like:

```
    if( driver == null )
    {
        if( which == CHROME )
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", which);
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if ( which == PHANTOM )
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.phantomjs.driver", which);
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        }
    }
```

What should I do to force it to work? Is it right Phantom library? Thanks.

Comment: Have you added  **phantomjsdriver** maven dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PhantomJSDriver (GhostDriver) you need to add the following Maven Dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, update the line `System.setProperty` with the absolute path of the `phantomjs` binary as follows :

```
File path=new File("C:\\path\\\to\phantomjs-x.x.x-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

**Note:** You can clean your project in IDE and use `Selenium-Java Clients` dependency only.

Comment: Thank you. This works. I didnt know which library to install.

Comment: @Čamo Good to hear

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for me:

1. download a driver: https://phantomjs.org/download.html
2. add this dependecy:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
       <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.4</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. add to your code:

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "pathToBin");
   driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
   ```

NOTE:
I'm using Selenium version 3.8.1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```